# Releasing a "synchronized" lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

Is something like this possible with `synchronized`, or do I need to use `java.util...Lock`:

```
public void outer() {
 synchronized(lock) {
  inner();
 }
}

public void inner() {
 thing1();
 release(lock) {
  result = doLongNetworkRequest();
 }
 thing2(result);
}
```

Comment: Do use `try-finally` (properly). / Are you sure you want to structure your code like this?

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: Yeah, I always use `finally` when dealing with locks. The structure is like this because in reality I have many inner methods and the locking is in `outer` for DRY reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't release the monitors held during a synchronized block unfortunately. You will have to use a lock or two to do what you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html). They have `lock()` and `unlock()`

Comment: This answer would be much more informative with an example. Could you please provide one?